# Alternative to triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

To eliminate the potential problems with triggers, what are some of the alternatives one may use to get the same functionality of reacting to an event fired on a INSERT action?

I have a database that needs to have some additional values added on insert. The INSERT is controlled by compiled code and cannot be changed.

EXAMPLE: The program inserts a string and from this string I need to supply an integer to a new field that points to a look-up table.

If there is an alternative to a trigger then please let me know some pros and cons to any alternative. The main reason for this is that Triggers are not allowed in our DB standards.

SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

Comment: Can you edit your question to reflect what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: What "potential problems" are you trying to avoid by an alternative method that does what triggers do?

Comment: depends on how much logic you need to implement, but you might look at defaults and computed columns to do simple things

Comment: The main reason for not using triggers is that the company does not allow them citing problems with maintenance in the future.

Comment: @Todd Moses: That rule is giving you maintenance problems in the present. Your job as a developer is to come up with solutions and to demonstrate when constraints are unreasonable. This is one of those situations where the rules need to be changed or at least circumvented in order to provide a solution. Rules like this shouldn't exist in the first place because they create problems like the one you're facing right now.

Comment: A simple "avoid unnecessary triggers" is generally a good enough guideline for most maintenance issues down the road. A hard-and-fast "never use triggers" is a foolish rule that should be rescinded as soon as possible before more harm is caused in the long run.

Comment: A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you determine your integer, based on the string being inserted?

One alternative you might want to look into are [computed columns in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx). If that matching is a pretty straightforward one (e.g. extract the character 10 through 14 from the string) or something like that, you could create a computed column to do so automagically - no trigger needed.

You can even make those computed columns persisted (physically stored as part of your tables) and create indices on these fields!

Computed columns are available from SQL Server 2000 on, persisted columns from SQL Server 2005.

Comment: The chars from the string is what I can use in a switch statement

Answer (score 6):

Alternatives to plain-old inserts can be done using stored procedures, triggers, or more complicated insert statements. Since you have no control over the insert statements, you won't be able to use stored procedures, either. So your only option is triggers.

What you're describing is precisely why triggers exist. If you need to accomplish this task then it can't be done under the constraints you've listed.

Triggers are the best option. Get the DB standards changed (or at least allow this task to be an exception) because they are flawed.

Comment: I agree but not able to change the standard.

Comment: @Todd Moses: I'd at least *try*. But I understand. Even if you could get the rules changed it won't be done soon enough for you to fix the issue at hand in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

I know that was asked a long time ago. With SQL Server 2008  "Change Data Capture" [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627369.aspx) was introduced. Another alternative, but only valid after 2008 R2 is "Change Tracking" [Setting up change tracking](https://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-introducing-change-tracking-part-1-3/). While you can query rows to filter ([look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql)) what was changed, this may or may not "resolve" the issues with triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are **the** way to perform an action after an event (insert, update, delete) occurs on a SQL table; the fact that they exist makes it unlikely that there's any tenable alternative.  It's unfortunate to say, but the DB standards you say are in place effectively prevent you from doing what you want without having some process running that periodically watches your table and then performs the action you need it to, or changing all your database CrUD operations to go through stored procedures which do what you want them to.  Since you say that the latter isn't possible -- you can't change the `INSERT` statements -- then you're left with just triggers.

Comment: BUT, when the trigger throws an exception - the database CRUD fails too! Just use CDC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/change-data-capture-functions-transact-sql to be save and don't interfere with the business logic.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005 now has something called an OUTPUT clause that can do additional processing after an INSERT (or other action) occurs. This [article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1381) covers more of the details. For instance, if you need to do processing after an INSERT command, you could do something like...

```
INSERT INTO Contact
(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)

OUTPUT INSERTED.ContactID, INSERTED.FirstName, INSERTED.MiddleName, INSERTED.LastName
INTO Contact_Audit    
VALUES
(@@SCOPE_IDENTITY, 'Joe', 'D.', 'Schmoe')
```

And you'd have your uniquely created ID for them available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use data history then go with system version history tables. you don't need to create trigger explicitly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -2):

Your options are limited here. I think your only other alternative is to do your inserts via a stored procedure call and put the extra code in the stored procedure.

Comment: The OP overtly says that the `INSERT` statements can't be modified, because they're in compiled code.

Answer (score -4):

I think we can implement trigger with hibernate event system nowdays despite of the performance impact.I didn't do that before.but I think it works

Comment: Hibernate is not mentioned in the question. The OP says the code is already compiled.